# OpenCV Mat of lists (or other type)

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am using OpenCV in C++ in order to compute optical flow. For this purpose, I need to store a list of objects for each pixel. These lists have varying sizes.

My idea was to store the lists in a `Mat` like so:

```
// frame is the input image. SimilarPixel is some custom struct.
cv::Mat_<std::list<SimilarPixel>> result(frame.rows, frame.cols);
```

So far it runs. However when I try to get or set an item in the `Mat` using `result.at<std::list<SimilarPixel>>(y, x)`, I get the following error:

[image]

Visual Studio then points me to following lines in the list standard header (the return statement):

```
iterator begin() _NOEXCEPT
{   // return iterator for beginning of mutable sequence
    return (iterator(this->_Nextnode(this->_Myhead()),
        &this->_Get_data()));
}
```

I am just a beginner with C++ (do have a lot of C# experience), so I might be making some kind of rookie mistake. I don't know if it is even possible in any way to create `Mat`s of any type in OpenCV, let alone `Mat`s of `list`s. Is there any way I can fix this? Please tell me if I should provide more of my code.

Comment: I have never used Mat_ template to store my custom objects, but I think the issue is in use of `at` method. Check documentation here: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html. If your `Mat_` is of type `double`, you can use method at as `at<double>` and not `at<list<double>>`. Let me know how it goes?

Comment: Also, why not just store the list of objects in SimilarPixel class.

Comment: @saurabheights Sorry, I accidentally posted the wrong initialization code. The type is actually `cv::Mat_<std::list<SimilarPixel>>`. I'll see what happens if I use something else than a list.

Comment: I wouldn't use a Mat like that.. it will probably not working as expected..

Comment: @saurabheights I received the same error when I encapsulated the list in a SimilarPixelSet struct. However, when I tried a `cv::Mat_<SimilarPixel>` and used no lists at all, it did work. I do need to get a list (or something similar) in there though.

Comment: Link to code: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L1983 . See, that all MatIterator_, MatConstIterator_ etc. should be able to work with your class, which is highly unlikely.